# Date / File lineage library / code

Tags: file, filesystems

I am looking for a program or library which is able to provide date/file lineage which is able to monitor a file or directory and which records the metadata about the history of the data object and its derivation history. This will be stuff like processes which access the file, the time, the changes made, etc.

Does anybody know of anything which is able to provide this functionality please? Unfortunately the only things I have found so far are research papers and they don't seem to have made their code available.

Good to hear any ideas people might have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This is my area of research, so I'm pretty up on what is available.)

Unfortunately, there's very little available for file level provenance like you are looking for.  The most advanced tools out there are PASS, from Harvard, which is a custom kernel, not stable enough for day to day use last I checked, or Burrito, from Stanford, which is not quite as fully featured, and is built using SystemTap.

Burrito: http://www.pgbovine.net/burrito.html

If you want to try PASS, the researchers are normally pretty friendly about sharing source.  But again, this code is not stable.

Another thing that you should be aware of is that provenance at that level is extremely bulky, so be prepared to dedicate a lot of disk space, or prune your provenance regularly.

Comment: Thanks! Totally forgot to look at this after not receiving a comment for a day or two. I will look at this and hope that it works like I want!